# How to use loader with master page and content page in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have asp.net page with master page.When i update the content page whole master page refresh for this i am use ajax script manager to update only content page.
now i want to use loader for master page and content page.but my loader is not work proper.when i update content page loader is not work.below is my code for content page

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/> 
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and my loader code is below i am use that in my content page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function () {

         $("form1").li(500);
     });
</script>
```

when refresh whole page loader work but for content page loader not work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Page = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
Page.add_beginRequest(OnBeginRequest);
Page.add_endRequest(endRequest);


function OnBeginRequest(sender, args) {
    blockUI();
}
function endRequest(sender, args) {
    unblockUI();
}
```

Hey, you need use this method from every single page.

Comment: WHERE CAN I USE THIS ONE

Comment: you need to use this script in  content place holder in every asp.net master web page

Comment: But sir now my whole page is load. i want only my content page load.

Comment: use **ScriptManager** in master page and use **UpdatePanel** in every content page and **use given script in above updatepanel**

Comment: i do same sir but when i use your script the loader is work but script manager not work

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to add loader and script in master page.

First you add image with some js popup property

```
<div id="statusPopup" style="display: none; z-index: 1000; left: 49%; top: 49%;">
        <div>              
            <img src="../Images/sprites.gif" alt="Loading......" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

and add script given below in master page

```
<!-- Note : Always keep this script at the bottom of page | To show loading / processing logo -->

   <script type="text/javascript">
       if (Sys != null) {
           Sys.Application.add_load(AppLoad);
       }

       function AppLoad() {
           Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequest);
           Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequest);

           function beginRequest(sender, args) {
               // show the popup


               document.getElementById("statusPopup").style.position = "fixed";
               document.getElementById("statusPopup").style.display = "";

           }

           function endRequest(sender, args) {
               document.getElementById("statusPopup").style.display = "none";
               seconds = 60 * 18;
           }
       }

</script>
```